# which is a more modern way to create web widgets?

Tags: ajax, iframe, widget

I want to create a new web widget, and I was wondering which is the best practice to do it.

Should I develop it like a normal page using PHP/Ruby/Python and use iFrame to make the widget code? Or should I develop it as an Ajax based application? or is there a better method than both?

What are the pros and cons for each?

Thanks

Comment: Without any details on what you think this "widget" will do or where it will run, it's pretty much impossible to answer.

Comment: Are we talking about W3C Widgets? http://www.w3.org/TR/widgets/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are many opportunities to do it:

- Client Side Programming Language JavaScript (pure JS, JQuery, ...), VBA (not really common), ...
- Server Side PHP, RoR, Python, ColdFusion, ASP.Net, ..
- you can load it per iFrames and so on (but you should NOT use iFrames because they are not good for SEO and this is **not a nice solution**.
- and so on ...

most CMS use the same language (in which they were written) - so they use a server side programming language. In PHP the Observer pattern and Hooks-concept are common ways to "connect" plugins/addons/widget/gadget with to website ...

Comment: - Client Side Programming Language JavaScript (pure JS, JQuery, ...)
I think this is the best because the SEO is given and its ajax based, so you can allow changes by user.

Comment: Yes of course! Most Web 2.0 Site use AJAX to perform different actions and content. But it's also possible to mix them up so you can write your plugins in PHP, but you insert them per AJAX - so your server generates different stuff, but at the client-side you don't have to change something. But be careful - if you don't know what you're doing! It is a small step to write websites with serious security issues.